# How to write each element of list in separate text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write each element of the list in a different file.

Let say we have a list:

```
dataset = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

I want to loop through the list and create text files depending upon the length of the list. So, in this case, there should be 3 text files and each will have content abc, def and ghi respectively.

My current code is below:

```
# This will read a text file, normalize it and remove stopwords from it using nltk.
import nltk, io, math
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# Read raw text
targetFile = open('text.txt')
rawtext = targetFile.read()

# Removing stopwords
stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_text = [i for i in rawtext.lower().split() if i not in stops]

# Count Number of words
total_words = len(filtered_text)

# Divide them equally into 10 different lists
chunk_size = math.floor(total_words/10)
n_lists_of_words = [filtered_text[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(filtered_text), chunk_size)]
if(len(n_lists_of_words) > 10):
    del n_lists_of_words[-1]

# Lets make list of strings instead of list of lists
list_of_str = [' '.join(x) for x in n_lists_of_words]


# Create 10 different files from above 10 elements of n_list_of_words list
for index, word in enumerate(n_lists_of_words):
    with io.FileIO("output_text_" + str(index) + ".txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(bytes(word), 'UTF-8')
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clean_my_text.py", line 35, in <module>
    file.write(bytes(word), 'UTF-8') 
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Did you got any errors?

Comment: Does `with open("output_text_" + str(count) + ".txt", "wb") as outfile: outfile.write(dataset[count])` not suit your purpose?

Comment: @RajatAgarwal Please copy & paste the error message into your post. Screenshots are never as reader-friendly as texts.

Comment: Are you sure `.write` takes two arguments?

Comment: Added error as text as well.

Comment: @Eric, yup. It was running fine when I did it for normal string.

Comment: Your error points to `file.write(bytes(n_lists_of_words[count]), 'UTF-8') `, but you have `file.write(bytes(dataset[count]), 'UTF-8')  `. Whats the complete code?

Comment: added complete code...

Comment: @tommy.carstensen, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. Able to do that. Here is the solution below, feel free to ask any relevant information with that:

```
# This will read a text file, normalize it and remove stopwords from it using nltk.
import nltk, io, math
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from string import punctuation

# Read raw text
targetFile = open('input_text.txt')
rawtext = targetFile.read()

# Remove punctuation
def strip_punctuation(s):
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c not in punctuation)
filtered_punc = strip_punctuation(rawtext)
print(filtered_punc)

# Removing stopwords
stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_text = [i for i in filtered_punc.lower().split() if i not in stops]

# Count Number of words
total_words = len(filtered_text)

# Divide them equally into 10 different lists
chunk_size = math.floor(total_words/10)
n_lists_of_words = [filtered_text[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(filtered_text), chunk_size)]
if(len(n_lists_of_words) > 10):
    del n_lists_of_words[-1]

# Lets make list of strings instead of list of lists
list_of_str = [' '.join(x) for x in n_lists_of_words]

# Print list values in seperate files
for index, word in enumerate(list_of_str):
    with open("Output" + str(index) + ".txt", "w") as text_file:
        print(word, file=text_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just a little bit wrong.
here is the last line corrected.
file.write(bytes(dataset[count], 'UTF-8'))

Comment: It doesn't work like this. You need string encoding but not like this. You can use different method, like I did in my answer below